# microstrip low pass filter design issues with sonnet

Tags: filter, low-pass, microwave, microstrip

I am trying to replicate the microstrip low-pass filter in SonnetLite from the book by [Jia-Sheng Hong - Microstrip Filters for RF Microwave Applications, 2nd Edition (Wiley Series in Microwave and Optical Engineering)   (2011, Wiley)](http://booksdescr.org/item/index.php?md5=164FD6C83B0A404797EFE084A27712EF)

However, the S12 graph shows that it is not a low pass filter at all. Could anyone advise why ?

I have attached the SonnetLite design file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4gS3HmGAxLjV-TZcRfUzytRfmQmowau/view?usp=sharing).

[image: incorrect s12 graph]

**box resonance warning analysis logs**

```
Run 1:  Sat Jun 22 00:27:07 2019.  SL291418.107194.
    Em version 15.53-Lite (32-bit Windows) on DESKTOP-DG59KC2 local.

Project:  C:\Users\kevin\Documents\sonnet\15.53-Lite\three-pole microstrip lowpass filter using open-circuited stubs\three-pole microstrip lowpass filter using open-circuited stubs.son.

Frequency:  0.001 GHZ

  Sonnet Warning EG2680:
  Circuit has potential box resonances.
  Circuit: primary structure
  The estimated box resonance frequencies are listed below.
  The calculations assume lossless materials, with a box filled with
  only the specified dielectric stackup materials.

  4.140 GHZ  TE Mode 1,0,1
  4.673 GHZ  TE Mode 1,0,2

  Only lowest order modes considered.

  See the chapter on package resonances in the Sonnet User's Guide.
  Date: Sat Jun 22 00:27:07 2019


  Sonnet Warning EG2680:
  Circuit has potential box resonances.
  Circuit: left box wall SOC magnetic wall standard
  The estimated box resonance frequencies are listed below.
  The calculations assume lossless materials, with a box filled with
  only the specified dielectric stackup materials.

  4.167 GHZ  TE Mode 0,1,1
  4.700 GHZ  TE Mode 0,1,2

  Only lowest order modes considered.

  See the chapter on package resonances in the Sonnet User's Guide.
  Date: Sat Jun 22 00:27:07 2019


Post-Analysis:
  Errors detected: 0    Warnings detected: 2.

Analysis completed Sat Jun 22 00:27:10 2019.
```

[image: microstrip lowpass filter layout]

Comment: have you actually got terminals connected to your filter? In other words, are you using sonnetlite correctly? That layout is a three pole lowpass filter, there's no question it ought to behave at least qualitatively like the book says.

Comment: @Neil_UK have you actually got terminals connected to your filter?   <-- What do you mean ?

Comment: I don't know sonnet specifically. How does it connect to the circuit under test? Does it have 50 ohm ports, or generalized transmission lines? It says it's found box resonances, so it's doing something. But does it know that it has to push current and voltage into those copper things that you've labelled 1 and 2. Or is there a ground plane under it, or implied at the boundaries of the box. The one thing I **do** know about 3d solvers in general is that they can be a pig to set up. Get a simple 'hello world' circuit working first, like a length of plain transmission line.

Comment: Someone helped me to solve most of the problems, and I have a [working low pass filter now](https://i.imgur.com/5RGY1M6.png).

But I am still very concerned about the correctness of the dielectric layer configuration. Any advise ?

Comment: You appear to have only 0.1mm of air above your conductor, but if that's real I would expect a much worse S11 from your filter. Does it ignore the thickness above and you enter the box height somewhere else? Having said that, the S11 is pretty rough, if sonnet is now set up properly I'd do another iteration on the dimensions. However, do model a simple bit of 50 ohm line from input to output, as a ground zero, make sure you get a reasonable S11.

Comment: @Neil_UK How is box height related to air dielectric layer ?  The "box" is 2D planar shape , I presume in the same direction of the planar microstrip filter ?

Comment: @Neil_UK I do not quite understand how [box size and free space cover affect box resonance](http://www.sonnetsoftware.com/support/downloads/manuals/st_users.pdf#page=397)

Comment: *How is box height related to air dielectric layer ?* The space between the top of the copper traces, and the underneath of the box cover is, what? Air, vacuum, specified, defaulted? What is its height, the thickness of the air layer, the height of the box specified elsewhere, what? What do you get when you model a plain length of 50 ohm transmission line? You have done that by now, haven't you? It would be silly to be trying to run before you've walked.

Comment: @W5VO this comment exchange is long enough for it to have prompted me to move it to chat, but it fails when I click the 'automatically move...' link. ref [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comments-would-you-like-to-automatically-m) in meta

Comment: See this [modified low pass microstrip filter](https://i.imgur.com/GLp3PSX.png)

Comment: What am I looking for? It looks like you've modified the 'air above' thickness, and the response has changed. What parameter does the air above thickness control? Is it something other than the height of a conducting box lid above the top surface of the copper? WHAT DO YOU GET WHEN YOU SIMULATE A SIMPLE STRAIGHT-THRU 50 OHM TRANSMISSION LINE (YES, SHOUTING)?